# Android not caputuring CellId and LocationId of slave sim in dual sim phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need the `cell id` and `location id` of slave sim; but it always returns 0 for both and my master slot sim is not present. How do I get it correctly? BTW, I have done proper checking whether `SIM`'s are present or not.

My code is:

```
final GsmCellLocation locationG = (GsmCellLocation) tel.getCellLocation();

    if (locationG != null)
    {
        cellId = locationG.getCid();
        lac = locationG.getLac();
        cellId = cellId & 0xffff;
    }
```

Comment: pls help me its urgunt..

Answer (score -1):

```
//you need to check if 2G or 3G

lac = String.valueOf(finalLocation.getLac()); 
cellId = String.valueOf(finalLocation.getCid());

if(3G) { 
   cellId= String.valueOf( Integer.valueOf( cellId)& 0xffff); 
   lac= String.valueOf( Integer.valueOf( lac)& 0xffff);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.